# How to generate different shared libraries in one CMakeFiles.txt according to one flag

Tags: cmake

The code is written in `C++`, but it also provides an `python-numpy` interface, thus we could compile it in two mode: `with-numpy` or `without-numpy`. In the `Makefile`, we could set  a variable to be the flag of that. For example, we could use `make` to generate `libmylib.so`, and also use `make numpy=1` to generate `libmylibpy.so`. In fact, in the `Makefile`, we use the `numpy=1` to define the `CXXFLAGS` with `-DNUMPY_INTERFACE`.

Now I want to change the project to a cmake project. The following is the simplest `CMakeFiles.txt` without the `numpy` interface:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
    set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
    set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
    project(mylib)

    include_directories(include)
    add_library(mylib SHARED
    include/common.h
    include/util.h
    src/common.cpp
    src/util.cpp
    )
```

How could I update the `CMakeFiles.txt` to a flag to generate different shared libraries with or without `numpy` interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a [build option](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/option.html).

```
# your library
add_library(mylib ...)

# add an option to include numpy
option(WITH_NUMPY "Determines whether to build with or without numpy.")

# if numpy is requested, set the NUMPY_INTERFACE preprocessor flag
if(WITH_NUMPY)
    target_compile_definitions(mylib PUBLIC NUMPY_INTERFACE)
endif()
```

You can set your custom `WITH_NUMPY` option either from the GUI interface, or from the command line using `cmake -DWITH_NUMPY=TRUE <path_to_source>`.

Note that the build option will be cached. That is, if you do not specify the option again on later runs, it will just keep reusing the option of the last run.

Note also that you only give the option when running CMake, but not when running the generated Makefile to build later. Therefore, if you want to change the option, you also need to re-run CMake.

Comment: Thank you, sir. But we should use the `target_compile_definitions` in `CMake 2.8.11` or higher.